# process.browser does not exist

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement [Swipeable Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#swipeable) from [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/). For performance reason, I would like to implement

```
const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
<SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={!iOS} disableDiscovery={iOS} />
```

as recommended on the page.

I have created a component as follows:

```
const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        icon: {
            marginLeft: "auto",
            color: "#505050"
        },
    }),
)


export default function MobileNav() {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <IconButton
                className={classes.icon}
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open navigation"
                edge="end"
            >
                <MenuRoundedIcon fontSize="large"/>
            </IconButton>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

and the compiler complains:

```
Property 'browser' does not exist on type 'Process'.  TS2339

     5 | 
     6 | 
  >  7 | const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)
       |                     ^
     8 | const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
     9 |     createStyles({
    10 |         icon: {
```

What is missing?

Comment: Hey!

I think the process variable is only available in the node env and electron if I'm not wrong.
You can try to console.log the `process` variable and see what is inside, in addition to it, you may have access to these if you are using a bundler as well such as webpack and parcel.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using typescript, `browser` does not exits on Process type by default, you should extend `Process` type by yourself

first create a folder named `typing` and create a `index.d.ts` file, then copy the following code

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Process extends NodeJS.Process {
    browser?: string
  }
}
```

add `typeRoots` property into `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "typeRoots": ["typing"]
}
```

Comment: Or we can do it without extending NodeJS.Process, just declare interface Process, which will be merged by Typescript with NodeJS native interface Process because of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

There was an update on [material-ui documentation](https://mui.com/components/drawers/).
Instead of having:

```
const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
<SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={!iOS} disableDiscovery={iOS} />
```

Change to:

```
const iOS = typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);

<SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={!iOS} disableDiscovery={iOS} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

when i install -D @types/node, then works.